Webform how to assign Evaluation form access to role other than Administrator
I have the modules Webform Version: 6.3.0-alpha2 with Webform Demo: Application/Evaluation System installed on Drupal 10.3.10.
I am using the 2 demo forms from Webform Demo: Application/Evaluation System but I can't get the Evaluation form attached to show for roles other than the Administrator.
I have the following build source added with the role "recruiter" added at /admin/webform/manage/demo_application_evaluation/source
application_evaluation:
  '#type': fieldset
  '#title': 'Application evaluation'
  '#attributes':
    style: 'background-color: #f5f5f2'
  '#format': custom
  '#format_html': |
    {{ children }}
    <div>{{ 'Submitted by'|t }}: <em>[webform_submission:user]</em></div>
    <hr/>
  '#format_text': |
    {{ children }}
    {{ 'Submitted by'|t }} [webform_submission:user]
    ------------------------------------------------------------
  '#access_create_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  '#access_update_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  '#access_view_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  rating:
    '#type': rating
    '#title': Rating
    '#required': true
    '#access_create_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter
    '#access_update_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter
    '#access_view_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter
  comments:
    '#type': textarea
    '#title': Comments
    '#access_create_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter
    '#access_update_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter
    '#access_view_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter

screenshot below (logged in as Administrator ) at /node/49/webform/submission/14 shows the "Application evaluation" form correctly but I also need to show it when logged in as "recruiter" role

Below is the "recruiter" role view

My goal is for my "recruiter" role to be able to evaluate job application submissions from my "jobseeker" role, which I created.
I have also added access for the recruiter role at /admin/webform/manage/demo_application as attached but I'm not quite sure if I'm on right track

Build source with recruiter role added below for /admin/webform/manage/demo_application
contact_information:
  '#title': 'Contact Information'
  '#type': section
  contact:
    '#type': contact
    '#title': Contact
    '#name__required': true
    '#company__access': false
    '#email__required': true
    '#phone__required': true
    '#address__required': true
    '#address_2__required': true
    '#city__required': true
    '#state_province__required': true
    '#postal_code__required': true
    '#country__required': true
resume:
  '#title': 'Your Resume'
  '#type': section
  resume_file:
    '#type': document_file
    '#title': Resume
    '#title_display': invisible
    '#states':
      visible:
        ':input[name="resume_method"]':
          value: attach
      required:
        ':input[name="resume_method"]':
          value: attach
      enabled:
        ':input[name="resume_method"]':
          value: attach
    '#file_extensions': 'rtf pdf doc docx'
cover:
  '#type': section
  '#title': 'Your Cover Letter'
  cover_letter:
    '#type': document_file
    '#title': 'Cover Letter'
    '#title_display': invisible
    '#states':
      visible:
        ':input[name="resume_method"]':
          value: attach
      required:
        ':input[name="resume_method"]':
          value: attach
      enabled:
        ':input[name="resume_method"]':
          value: attach
    '#file_extensions': 'rtf pdf doc docx'
application_status:
  '#type': details
  '#title': 'Application Status'
  '#open': true
  '#admin': true
  '#access_create_roles': {  }
  state:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'Application State'
    '#options':
      completed: Completed
      in_review: 'In review'
      accepted: Accepted
      rejected: Rejected
    '#options_display': side_by_side
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
  completed_date:
    '#type': datetime
    '#title': 'Application Completed Date'
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
    '#access_update_roles': {  }
    '#access_view_roles':
      - authenticated
  in_review_date:
    '#type': datetime
    '#title': 'Application In Review Date'
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
    '#access_update_roles': {  }
    '#access_view_roles':
      - authenticated
  accepted_date:
    '#type': datetime
    '#title': 'Application Accepted Date'
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
    '#access_update_roles': {  }
    '#access_view_roles':
      - authenticated
  rejected_date:
    '#type': datetime
    '#title': 'Application Rejected Date'
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
    '#access_update_roles': {  }
    '#access_view_roles':
      - authenticated
evaluation_summary:
  '#type': fieldset
  '#title': 'Evaluation Summary'
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#access_create_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  '#access_update_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  '#access_view_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  evaluation_rating:
    '#type': rating
    '#title': 'Average Rating'
    '#test': '0'
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
    '#access_update_roles': {  }
    '#access_view_roles':
      - authenticated
    '#step': '.1'
  evaluation_count:
    '#type': number
    '#title': 'Number of Evaluations'
    '#test': '0'
    '#access_create_roles': {  }
    '#access_update_roles': {  }
    '#access_view_roles':
      - authenticated
evaluation_details:
  '#type': details
  '#title': 'Evaluation Details'
  '#access_create_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  '#access_update_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  '#access_view_roles':
    - administrator
    - recruiter
  evaluation_submissions:
    '#type': view
    '#access_create_roles':
      - recruiter
    '#access_update_roles':
      - recruiter
    '#access_view_roles':
      - administrator
      - recruiter
    '#display_on': view
    '#name': webform_demo_application_evaluations
    '#display_id': embed
    '#arguments':
      - '[webform_submission:sid]'

Maybe this is a global access or views issue? Help appreciated. Thanks

ultimately I'm trying to build a test job application website where multiple recruiters can login and administer their job postings while job seekers can manager their applications.

Solved. The webform block was applied to the Claro theme in Block Layout and needed to be applied to the theme (Barrio) that I was using instead.
Works fine now.
Now how to remove tabs at /node/54/webform/submission/23

